# Como obter dados da linha anterior em SQL?

Tags: sql

Como criar uma coluna com o valor da linha anterior de outra coluna?
Segue exemplo, tenho a coluna time e quero criar a coluna `time_lag`:

```
Tabela inicial:  
id | title   | time  | domain  
32   title1    12:30   domain1  
33   title1    13:30   domain2  
34   title2    14:20   domain1  
35   title2    14:50   domain2  
36   title3    15:30   domain5
```

Resultado esperado:

```
id | title   | time  | domain |time_lag  
32   title1    12:30   domain1  
33   title1    13:30   domain2 12:30  
34   title2    14:20   domain1 13:30  
35   title2    14:50   domain2 14:20  
36   title3    15:30   domain5 14:50
```

Comment: Precisas de fazer isso permanente na tabela? Não seria suficiente uma querie com esse resultado?

Comment: @Sergio, preciso dessa coluna de forma permanente.

Comment: Mas se não quiser mexer na tabela, existe a função lag, que poderá ser bem mais útil:
[http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/11/15/sql-server-introduction-to-lead-and-lag-analytic-functions-introduced-in-sql-server-2012/](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/11/15/sql-server-introduction-to-lead-and-lag-analytic-functions-introduced-in-sql-server-2012/)

Comment: @HenriquePizarro, qual o banco de dados e versão você esta utilizando ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se seu id for sempre auto incremento, basta você fazer um sub-select e passar o *id - 1* do select externo.

```
declare @teste table
(
   id int,
   title varchar(10),
   time time, 
   domain varchar(10)
)


insert into @teste values

(32,   'title1'   ,'12:30'   ,'domain1'),  
(33 ,  'title1'    ,'13:30'   ,'domain2'),    
(34,   'title2'    ,'14:20'   ,'domain1'),    
(35,   'title2'    ,'14:50'   ,'domain2'),    
(36 ,  'title3'    ,'15:30'   ,'domain5')  


select * , (select time from @teste t1 where t1.id = t2.id - 1) as time_lag
from @teste t2
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou ainda;

```
select * , (select top 1 time from @teste t1 where t1.id < t2.id order by time desc ) as time_lag
from @teste t2
```

Troque o top 1 por rownum = 1 caso seja oracle ou LIMIT 1 se for mysql.

Comment: No ponto de vista da normalização seria melhor utilizar essa abordagem (diferente da que o autor pediu) de se fazer um select mesmo, como você fez. Já que o resultado da coluna time_lag é um valor calculado. Porém você deve se atentar ao fato de que ao remover algum registro da tabela quebraria a lógica do -1

Comment: @FelipeNascimento, verdade, resolvido.

Answer (score 2):

Voce pode criar uma nova coluna a sua tabela e na hora de inserir fazer algo do tipo:

```
INSERT INTO minhatabela (title, time, domain, time_lag) VALUES 
(
    'title1',
    '12:30', /*Não sei o tipo deste campo apesar do nome*/
    'domain1',
     SELECT time FROM minhatabela ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
)
```

Isso faria que o valor de time_lag fosse o valor de time do último registro inserido